# How can I owner lock this command in discord.js v12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make this command so only I can run it, no luck so far.

```js
client.on("message", message => { 
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    if (command === "test") {
        console.log((chalk.yellow)`You ran a command: test`)
        message.channel.send('test')
    }
});
```

I tried using

```
if (!message.author.id === config.ownerID) return;
```

and

```
if (message.author.id !== config.ownerID) return;
```

When I used the first one, the command worked but everyone was able to run it, and when I used the second one no one was able to run it at all. I don't get any error logs nor crashes. Anyone knows the correct code?

Comment: The first one is definitely incorrect, as you're comparing a boolean to a string/number. The second one should work. Have you checked the value of `config.ownerID` and `message.author.id`? Are you sure `config.ownerID` is correct? Is it a string?

Comment: What does `config` resolve to?

Comment: Yes, "ownerID": ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"] That's how it looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, the first one is definitely incorrect, as you're converting `message.author.id` to a boolean by using the logical NOT operator (`!`). Your second attempt could work if `config.ownerID` was a string, but you can't compare a string to an array.

If your `config.ownerID` is an array of IDs, you can use the [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check if the `message.author.id` is included the given array:

```js
if (config.ownerID.includes(message.author.id)) return
```